# PHP echo issue while in a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, echo, buffering

I read in a csv file by using a while loop:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, null, ",")) !== FALSE)
```

and i want to skip the first row because this is the title row and i want to display on the screen "first line skipped".

```
if($data[0]=="title")
echo "Title row..skipping<br />";  
else
//do stuff
```

The problem is since its in a while loop it prints out "Title row...skipping" a bunch of times shown here:

```
Checking row 0...
Title row..skipping
Title row..skipping
Title row..skipping
Title row..skipping
Title row..skipping
Title row..skipping
Title row..skipping
Checking row 1...
```

what should i do so it only prints it out once? does it have something to do with php's output buffering?

Comment: Your output looks really odd. Are you sure your csv file is formatted correctly?

Comment: Post more code. Your problem isn't in the part that we can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($data[0]=="title") {
  if (!$skipped) {
    echo "Title row..skipping<br />";
    $skipped = true;
  }
}
else
//do stuff
```

Comment: clever ;) i should have thought of that

Answer (score 1):

Or call `fgetcsv($handle, null, ",")` once without assignment, to move the handler forward by one line:

```
fgetcsv($handle, null, ",");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, null, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a certain that you only need to skip the first line then;

```
if(!$skipped)
{
    echo "Title row..skipping<br />";
    $skipped = true;
}
else
//do stuff
```

Comment: Note: Aspired from Ast's answer ;P

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be more elegant to use foreach:

```
foreach data as item {
  if (item == "title") {
   echo "Skipping title<br/>";
  }
}
```

How you have it now, you are checking `if (data[0] == "title")` every time you loop. `data[0]` will always equal "title", so it will always evaluate to true. You could increment an `$index` variable and do something like `if (data[$index] == $title)` then `$index++` near the bottom of the loop, but why do that when `foreach` will essentially do that for you.